# Blogger post url prefix

Tags: javascript, html, xml, url, blogger

It looks like this when I use `data:post.url` in Blogger;

`blogname.blogspot.com/2021/01/post-name.html`

the shape I want to show; `/2021/04/post-name.html`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with JavaScript

```
"<data:post.url/>".replace("<data:blog.homepageUrl/>","/");
```

**Edit**

Place the following code before `</body>`

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isMultipleItems'>
    <script>
            document.querySelectorAll('.entry-title-link').forEach(function (e) {
                e.href = e.href.replace('<data:blog.homepageUrl/>','/');
            });
    </script>
</b:if>
```

Comment: I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Ok, but the browser will auto redirect the URL to `blogname.blogspot.com/2021/01/post-name.html`. Can you clear the purpose of that, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: it has not changed in the source.

Comment: Because the url changed using Javascript, you will not see the effect until the page gets loaded

Comment: Can I do it without javascript.

Comment: No, there is no way to do it without JS.